# How to align 2 divs inside another div?

Tags: css, html

My requirement is I have two links at left side and if I click on a link, respective page should get displayed on the right side.
how can make this arrangement using  tags.
I tried as the below, but its not showing side by side. where as DisplayData gets appeared at the bottom of links. Thanks in advance..

```
<div id="accountstabs-1">
     <div id="links" style="text-align:left">
         <li><a href="#DisplayData" id="settings1" onclick="manage(this.id)">Manage</a></li>
         <li><a href="#DisplayData-2" id="settings2" onclick="manage(this.id)">Users</a></li>
     </div>
     <div id="DisplayData" style="text-align:right">
         <table class="data">
              <thead>
                <tr> 
                  <th>
                    First Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Last Name
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS:

```
#accountstabs-1>div {
    float : left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4E88/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use floats instead of `text-align` to position elements. (`text-align` should only be used for text.)

Check out [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tvumq/).

I updated your HTML like this:

```
<div id="accountstabs-1">
    <div id="links" >
        <li><a href="#DisplayData" id="settings1" onclick="manage(this.id)">Manage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#DisplayData-2" id="settings2" onclick="manage(this.id)">Users</a></li>
     </div>
     <div id="DisplayData" >
         <table class="data">
              <thead>
                <tr> 
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>​
```

Notice that I removed the two `text-align` inline styles from the divs, and added the new div near the bottom with class `clr`.

Then the CSS looks like this:

```
#links {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#DisplayData {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

/* clearfix */
.clr { clear: both; }
```

The purpose of the "clearfix" is to make sure that any elements added after your right column get displayed underneath the columns properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the styles in a separate CSS file, but the following should work;

```
<div id="accountstabs-1" style="width:400px">
     <div id="links" style="display:block;float:left;width:200px">
         <li><a href="#DisplayData" id="settings1" onclick="manage(this.id)">Manage</a></li>
         <li><a href="#DisplayData-2" id="settings2" onclick="manage(this.id)">Users</a></li>
     </div>
     <div id="DisplayData" style="display:block;float:right;width:200px">
         <table class="data">
              <thead>
                <tr> 
                  <th>
                    First Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Last Name
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to put `display: block` on the divs since divs are, by default, block elements. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

div is a block element and it take the whole place horizantly, 
to place another div in parallel you need to use css property float left .
use style property `style="float:left"`.

`<div id="accountstabs-1">
     <div id="links" style="text-align:left; float:left">
         <li><a href="#DisplayData" id="settings1" onclick="manage(this.id)">Manage</a></li>
         <li><a href="#DisplayData-2" id="settings2" onclick="manage(this.id)">Users</a></li>
     </div>
     <div id="DisplayData" style="text-align:right">
         <table class="data">
              <thead>
                <tr> 
                  <th>
                    First Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Last Name
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>`